# is there Better way to do this kind database schema design, mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, query-performance

P.S. Hopefully I am not posting in the wrong place.  If I am, please let me know where to post.

I am currently using laravel with query builder instead of eloquent for a small self project.
I am using the below as examples.

For example.
I have a document with some fields such as

```
title,
identifier,
contents
```

none of those are unique though.
BUT the same document will have the same identifier, this is because the document can be rewritten several times, so the there will be some rows with the same info.  Some of you might ask why not using update instead but due to request update is not an option.

Each document can have lots notes, but all the document with the same `identifier` will be reading the same notes

for notes, I have field such as

```
identifier  // this is the identifier from the document
contents  // just contents of the notes
```

Because the `identifer` in `notes` is not unique, I am not able to index it to make querying faster.  Even if I added a `FK` referencing `notes` with `document_id` but after I get the `notes`  I still have to go through the whole `notes` to find all with the same `identifier` so to me, adding `FK` doesn't seem to help much.

Is there a better way to do this, or I am thinking the logic completely wrong?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are you keeping multiple versions of the same document?  If so, what column distinguishes one version from a nother?

Comment: @RickJames yes there are multiple versions, but there isn't a column to distinguish. There can, but any version of the `document` will be able to get ALL the `notes` even if the notes are added from different version.  version 1 and version 2 will see the same notes

Comment: But how do I tell version 1 from version 2?  Be reading the document?  Won't you need an SQL query that says "get me the 'latest' version?

Comment: @RickJames well the thing is, if I query the documents, all version will need to be shown.  Not just the latest document. That is why there isn't version here, the user doesn't care which version.

Comment: Do you need them displayed in some particular order?

Comment: @RickJames as for notes yes, but it has `created_at` which will be the order, as for the document itself, nope.  Any order would be fine for my knowledge but does orders matter?